# startActivityForResult() works differently on android 9

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie, android-studio-3.4

My application works fine on android phones from 4 to 8.1.
StartActivityForResult works properly and calls the intent that was previously declared with the target activity and then performs the code in the activity in which I am currently.
Unfortunately, on the phone with android 9, the sequence of executing the application code changes.
Firstly the code is executed in the activity1, which results in a NullPointerException - and the intent is called afterwards. Activity2 is initializing object that causes null pointer exception:

Android 8.1 sequence:

```
Activity1 -> startActivityForResult -> Activity2 -> Result Activity1 -> Activity1 code -> OK
```

Android 9 sequence

```
Activity1 -> startActivityForResult -> Activity1 code (NullPointerException) -> (if I comment the code in Activity1 -> Activity 2 -> Result Activity1 )
```

I tried to change gradle files, add flags to the intent, set android.enableR8 = false, unfortunately nothing helped.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("...", doc.id);
i.putExtra("...", method);
i.putExtra(Activity2.PARAMS, activity2SearchParams);
startActivityForResult(i, ActivityRequestCode.NEW);
```

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

I'd like to preserve 8.1 order of execution. Please help.

Comment: It is not clear what "Activity1 code" is and where you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Hi. I edited the question.

Comment: I suggest that you provide a [mcve]. For example, you might provide the actual code that is the source of "Activity2 is initializing object that causes null pointer exception", and explain why Activity2 cares about what Activity1 is doing and when it is doing it.

Comment: The problem concerns the sequence. Null pointer is just a result of something that must have changed with android 9.